# SQL Server : full-text pdf search results using contains and ifilters

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf

I installed iFilter in my SQL Server and can verify that I have pdf support with the following command

```
SELECT document_type, path 
FROM sys.fulltext_document_types 
WHERE document_type = '.pdf'
```

I get

> .pdf  C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe PDF iFilter 11 for 64-bit platforms\bin\PDFFilter.dll

I created the full-text index using management studio and created a column that stores the text `.pdf` and set that as the "type column", I also created a column that stores the `pdf` itself as `varbinary(max)` and can verify its in there by retrieving the file with c# back and reading it. However while I can search text fields using this search query

```
select * 
from tblresume 
where contains(textResume, 'test text')
```

I cannot search pdf columns using this method

```
select * 
from tblresume 
where contains(pdfResume, 'test text')
```

No errors, I just get no search results, can anyone please help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Using the FTS DMV's can you tell if any of the documents were actually indexed?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174971.aspx

Comment: Not sure what that is, can you let me know how to use the FTS DMV's? I googled it but can't seem to understand what that is.